# how to write db2 query with join and export clause in unix

Tags: unix, join, db2, export

I am getting errors in this query with SQLSTATE=42703  SQL0206N

```
db2 export to prc_sec_01.txt of del 
SELECT PRICE.PRC_SECURITY_ID,
 \(decimal\(PRICE.PRC_PRICE\)\),
 PRICE.PRC_CURRENCY,PRICE.PRC_CURRENCY
FROM RISKAPP.PRICE as PRICE
 inner join RISKAPP.SECURITY as SECURITY
 on PRICE.PRC_SECURITY_ID = SECURITY.SEC_SECURITY_ID
 and SECURITY.SEC_TYPE = "E"
 AND SECURITY.SEC_MATURITY_DATE >='20141118'
 AND PRICE.PRC_EXTRACT_PERIOD ='PBNS'
 AND PRICE.PRC_LAST_UPDATE_TMS >= '2014-10-01'
```

Comment: A.<column name>" is not valid in the context where it is used.

Comment: @DariusX. what this is suppose to mean? is it some kind of syntax error?

Comment: Does the message also tell you what column name is triggering this error?

Comment: You may want to enclose the entire command in double quotes to avoid the shell interpreting special characters in it.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to test the query works as desired. Please try to run just the select. If there are many rows, you can limit the result with fetch first x rows only

```
db2 "
SELECT PRICE.PRC_SECURITY_ID,
 \(decimal\(PRICE.PRC_PRICE\)\),
 PRICE.PRC_CURRENCY,PRICE.PRC_CURRENCY
FROM RISKAPP.PRICE as PRICE
 inner join RISKAPP.SECURITY as SECURITY
 on PRICE.PRC_SECURITY_ID = SECURITY.SEC_SECURITY_ID
 and SECURITY.SEC_TYPE = "E"
 AND SECURITY.SEC_MATURITY_DATE >='20141118'
 AND PRICE.PRC_EXTRACT_PERIOD ='PBNS'
 AND PRICE.PRC_LAST_UPDATE_TMS >= '2014-10-01'
 fetch first 10 rows only"
```

If the previous query works well, you just need to add the export statement at the beginning.

```
db2 export to prc_sec_01.txt of del 
SELECT PRICE.PRC_SECURITY_ID,
...
```

As recommended by @mustaccio, it is a good practice to surround everything into quotes, instead of escape characters:

```
db2 "export to prc_sec_01.txt of del 
SELECT PRICE.PRC_SECURITY_ID,
 decimal(PRICE.PRC_PRICE),
 PRICE.PRC_CURRENCY,PRICE.PRC_CURRENCY
FROM RISKAPP.PRICE as PRICE
 inner join RISKAPP.SECURITY as SECURITY
 on PRICE.PRC_SECURITY_ID = SECURITY.SEC_SECURITY_ID
 and SECURITY.SEC_TYPE = "E"
 AND SECURITY.SEC_MATURITY_DATE >='20141118'
 AND PRICE.PRC_EXTRACT_PERIOD ='PBNS'
 AND PRICE.PRC_LAST_UPDATE_TMS >= '2014-10-01'"
```

Comment: i m getting error like the column name is not correct in the context where it is used!

Comment: It turns out that any special character can be used with a query once if we used " " for the query.. thanks

Comment: Sure, you define strings in SQL with single quotes, not with double: SEC_TYPE = 'E'